# Calculating the number of days between two dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic, sql-date-functions

I am using the PostgreSQL function `date_part()` to calculate the (inclusive) number of days passed between two dates.

```
select date_part('day', '2019-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp
                      - '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp);
```

Running this query in DBeaver returns 1 day less than expected:

| date_part |
| --- |
| 364.0 |

It would be as simple as adding `+1` to the result, but then the following sentence would return `1` day, which seems wrong:

```sql
select 1 + date_part('day', '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp
                          - '2019-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp);
```

| ?column? |
| --- |
| 1.0 |

Is there a better way to have a trusted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *include* both date boundaries, adding `+ 1` is actually the right thing to do. There is *one* day between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-01' according to your own definition.

Since you speak of **dates**, not timestamps, there's a simpler way:

```sql
SELECT date '2019-12-31'
     - date '2019-01-01'
     + 1 AS range;
```

| range |
| --- |
| 365 |

[Subtracting dates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE) returns `integer`.
If the input is a `timestamp` values, just cast to `date` to truncate the time component:

```
SELECT ts1::date - ts2::date + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant

```
select date_part('day', '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp - '2019-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp);
```

because it's absolutly correct, that at 00:00:00 Dec 31 - right after 23:59:59 Dec 30 - it's only 364 full days passed.

Comment: Yes, I saw that even 1s left is enough to get the wrong 30 days value in `select date_part('day', '2019-1-31 23:59:59'::timestamp - '2019-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp);`

Comment: Using dates won't help either: `select '2019-12-31'::date - '2019-1-1 00:00:00'::date; 364` as  I'm pretty sure the dates get cast to a timestamp as midnight.

Comment: Casting to date means setting time to '00:00:00', I suppose.

Comment: I also found this sentence, but renders 364 days too for a normal year `select date '2019-12-31' - date '2019-1-1';`

Comment: Again: this  *actually is* 364 days, the 365th day - 2019-12-31 - *is not in that range*

Comment: As for my request, I am searching for an inclusive solution. Anyway, your solution is not safe as it sometimes counts the last day and others not.

Comment: This renders 364 days: `select date '2019-12-31' - date '2019-1-1';`. Assuming that is ok then `select date '2019-1-2' - date '2019-1-1';` should render 0, but it renders 1.

Comment: I am assuming that a conditional `if` maybe unavoidable for two identical dates.

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout way:

```
select 
   count(*) AS days 
from 
   generate_series('2019-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
                   '2019-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp, '1 day');
 days 
------
  365
```

Comment: Good try Adrian, but it fails for two identical dates or for two near ones. Check `select 
   count(*) AS days 
from 
   generate_series('2019-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp, 
                   '2019-1-1 00:00:00'::timestamp, '1 day');`

Comment: I am assuming that a conditional `if` maybe unavoidable for two identical dates.

Comment: Basically the idea is calculating the `doy` (day of year) of both dates and take the difference between those two integer.  If you meant to have an inclusive solution you should add +1 to that difference but then it is when the case of two identical dates fails rendering 1. You probably need a condition using  a `where` clause or an `if` clause in plpgsql

Comment: Sorry, I meant `when`, not `where`.