# Find the first negative value if exist and then do a substraction between dates

Tags: postgresql, date, subquery, case, negative-number

I have the next table

| Product | Plant | Store | Week | Date | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 0 | 2001-01-01 | -24 |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 1 | 2001-01-08 | -60 |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 2 | 2001-01-16 | -60 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | 0 | 2001-01-01 | 10 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | 1 | 2001-01-08 | -20 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | 2 | 2001-01-16 | -30 |
| 013579 | C678 | 1A3 | 0 | 2001-01-01 | 10 |
| 013579 | C678 | 1A3 | 1 | 2001-01-08 | 20 |
| 013579 | C678 | 1A3 | 2 | 2001-01-16 | 30 |

So I would like to get the first negative value then get its date and do a substract between the first date (which is in week=0) and the date for the first negative value, but if is not negative values then get the last positive value and do a substract between the first date (which is in the colum Week and value=0) and the last date (which is in the colum Week and value=2). So at the end I'll get a table like this:

| Product | Plant | Store | DaysDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 0 |
| 789123 | B345 | 123 | 7 |
| 013579 | C678 | 1A3 | 15 |

The result in the column DaysDiff is due to `(2001-01-01)-(2001-01-01)=0`,`(2001-01-01)-(2001-01-08)=7` and `(2001-01-01)-(2001-01-16)=15`.

The query I wrote was this:

```
SELECT
    Product,
    Plant,
    Store,
    CASE
        WHEN MIN(CASE WHEN Stock < 0 THEN Date END) IS NOT NULL THEN
            DATEDIFF(WEEK, 
                MIN(CASE WHEN Stock < 0 THEN Date END),
                MIN(CASE WHEN Week = 0 THEN Date END)
            )
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(WEEK, 
                MAX(CASE WHEN Week = 0 THEN Date END),
                MIN(Date)
            )
    END AS DaysDiff
FROM Table
GROUP BY
    Product,
    Plant,
    Store
ORDER BY Product, Plant, Store;
```

But I only get one result.

| Product | Plant | Store | DaysDiff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A123 | Z12 | 0 |

Any help?

Comment: **1)** Both the official week numbering and your example start from `week 1` not `week 0`. **2)** How are you getting even that 1 result with this query? `Store < 0` throws `ERROR:  operator does not exist: text < integer`: you have `store` values with letters in them.

Comment: Already edit the table and the information in the query. Thanks!

Comment: Reality check. How did you get any result? You indicated Postgres database but the central part of your query is the function `DATEDIFF`. Unfortunately, that function *does not exist* in Postgres. unless  That is unless it is a user defined function; in which case you should post it.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler does it:

```sql
SELECT product, plant, store
     , COALESCE(min(date) FILTER (WHERE stock < 0), max(date)) - min(date) AS days_diff
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1,2,3
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kUBUswHv)

There is no <strike>`DATEDIFF()`</strike> function in Postgres. (You may be [thinking of MySQL?](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff))
To get the difference between *dates*, just subtract. See:

- [Calculating the number of days between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68787291/calculating-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/68787771#68787771)

About the aggregate `FILTER` clause:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/aggregate-columns-with-additional-distinct-filters/27141193#27141193)

[`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to finalize.

About the (optional!) short syntax with ordinal numbers:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)